# Exception before a wcf transfer file

Tags: c#, wcf

I used [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP) and my code is

```
private void dialogBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file;
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
        TransferServiceClient clientUpload = new TransferServiceClient();
        RemoteFileInfo uploadRequestInfo = new RemoteFileInfo();

        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            uploadRequestInfo.FileName = file;
            uploadRequestInfo.Length = fileInfo.Length;
            uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = stream;
            //clientUpload.UploadFile(uploadRequestInfo);
            clientUpload.UploadFile(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, stream);                      
        }                
    }           
}
```

During the `clientUpload.UploadFile(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, stream);` I receive an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>    Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\upload\Book1.xlsx'.

But, the Book1.xlsx is not inside upload folder. It's at the Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the service implementation of the `UploadFile` method in the example is as follows:

```
public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
{
    FileStream targetStream = null;
    Stream sourceStream =  request.FileByteStream;

    string uploadFolder = @"C:\upload\";

    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, request.FileName);

    using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, 
                          FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //read from the input stream in 65000 byte chunks

        const int bufferLen = 65000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
        {
            // save to output stream
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        targetStream.Close();
        sourceStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Note the line

```
string uploadFolder = @"C:\upload\";
```

You need to change that to some existing folder where you want the uploaded files to be **stored**.

Comment: Thank you I did it! I created an upload folder on the service machine but why do i need an upload folder on my client machine?

Comment: @George You don't need it at client machine. Only if you are debugging (running both client and service on one and the same machine). Note that you are receiving a Fault exception, which means the error is from service.